# Calculating sum of multiple async callbacks

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am still learning Javascript properly and read a few threads on here about asynchronity ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)).
Unfortunately, I have still trouble to find a solution to my problem. I am calling an API in async fashion and would like to create a sum out of the response that I am receiving of multiple async calls.

Let's say I want my code to perform an action if my "sum" has a value of 40. Async call "A" returns 6, async call "B" returns 8, and so on until we finally reach the value of 40.
How can I create such a sum, as my calls are all async?
Would it require to write each async result to a database and pull the value up in the next async call?
Is there a better solution for this?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT: To make things easier to understand I will add some source code:

Webhook.js

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  if (middleware.active)
    middleware.handle(req.body) // <--- this gives me one result
  res.sendStatus(200)
});
```

Basically, I will receive multiple webhook calls. "middleware.handle" will send an API call to third party application. I want to take the result from that API call and add it to the result of another API call from another webhook request.

As you can see, I don't know when my webhook will be triggered, neither how many times it will be triggered before reaching my desired total of 40.

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: You would have to use async wait and promise state "fulfilled". However, please add your code here to give correct suggestions

Comment: Database, or some other form of persistence in between posts is what's needed here.

Comment: Any advice what would be the best solution? I am not storing much data. Just some simple sums.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise.all([apiCallOne, apiCallTwo]).then(values => sum(values))`
sum being a function that sums an array of numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can await for both in a do/while loop then do the rest of the logic

```
async function myFunc() {
   let valA = 0;
   let valB = 0;
   do {
      valA += await fetch('https://api.url.com/a');
      valB += await fetch('https://api.url.com/b');
   } while((valA + valB) < 40 );
```

You can also do each one in its do/while loop if you want to request value from one only at a time then check condition.